# Why am I stuck on a sign-in page while setting up a Proxy on FireTV 4K

Tags: amazon-fire-tv

I've got a problem proxying traffic on Amazon FireTV 4k Stick, I'm using the following command to push the cert.

`adb push charles-ssl-proxying-certificate.pem /storage/emulated/0/Download`

Then I use this to install the cert.

`adb shell am start -a "android.intent.action.VIEW" -d "file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/charles-ssl-proxying-certificate.pem" -t "application/x-x509-ca-cert"`

all good it presents the sign-in page to re-authenticate the user, I enter my credentials nothing happens? I'm on this screen for ever until screen saver or something kicks in and I'm back to home screen. My networking is working, I'm able to play videos on prime. I'm able to download apps. But somehow Amazon doesn't allow myself to authenticate. I even disbaled 2fa. I've reset to factory defaults many times.

what am I missing? please can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there appears to be a bug in FireOS6, that does not allow clicks on the sign-in button. As a workaround use scrcpy on the same network.

Answer (score 0):

With your remote control, select the password field and then use `adb` to run the command:

```
adb shell input keyevent 66
```

Answer based on hitting the same issue and overcome it using the instructions provided in this link:
http://www.unibia.com/unibianet/systems-networking/install-additional-tls-root-cas-amazon-fire-tv